# How to calculate average classification report across all folds?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I am trying to do a binary class classification. Since I have a small dataset (275 samples), I have done Leave-one-out cross validation and want to get the average classification report and AUROC/AUPRC across all folds.

I have closely followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567557) to arrive at my results, but I cannot understand what the code is doing in the last line.

```
for i in classifiers:
    print(i)
    originalclass = []
    predictedclass = []
    model=i
    loo = LeaveOneOut()
    print('Scores before feature selection')
    scores = cross_val_score(model, subset, y,cv=loo,scoring=make_scorer(classification_report_with_accuracy_score))
    print("CV score",np.mean(cross_val_score(model,subset,y,cv=loo,scoring='roc_auc')))
    print(classification_report(originalclass, predictedclass))
    print('Scores after feature selection')
    X_reduced=feature_reduction_using_RFECV(model,subset,y)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X_reduced, y,cv=loo,scoring=make_scorer(classification_report_with_accuracy_score))
    print("CV score",np.mean(cross_val_score(model,X_reduced,y,cv=loo,scoring='roc_auc')))
    print(classification_report(originalclass, predictedclass))
```

Where exactly is the averaging happening in the above code? I am calculating the mean CV score and printing it. But the line after that confuses me the most. I am initializing originalclass and predictedclass variable in the beginning,but where is it being used before printing in the last line?

```
print(classification_report(originalclass, predictedclass))
```

**Edited code**

```
for i in classifiers:
    print(i)
    originalclass = y
    model=i
    loo = LeaveOneOut()
    print('Scores before feature selection')
    y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, subset, y, cv=loo)
    print(classification_report(originalclass, y_pred))
    print("CV score",np.mean(cross_val_score(model,subset,y,cv=loo,scoring='roc_auc')))
    print(classification_report(originalclass, y_pred))
    print('Scores after feature selection')
    X_reduced=feature_reduction_using_RFECV(model,subset,y)
    y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X_reduced, y, cv=loo)
    classification_report(originalclass, y_pred)
    print("CV score",np.mean(cross_val_score(model,X_reduced,y,cv=loo,scoring='roc_auc')))
    print(classification_report(originalclass, y_pred))
```

Comment: Your question does not make any sense; you can certainly average CV scores (here with `np.mean`), but you *cannot* "average" classification reports. Please see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) to understand exactly what a classification report actually is

Comment: In cross validation we train on every n-1 folds and test on the nth fold. As a result for every run, we get a confusion matrix and consequently the classification report. Can I not average the sensitivity/specificity etc for every fold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
print("CV score",np.mean(cross_val_score(model,X_reduced,y,cv=loo,scoring='roc_auc')))
```

you print the average cross-validated `roc_auc` metric of your model under the `cv` i.e. LeaveOneOut scheme.

---

The next command:

```
print(classification_report(originalclass, predictedclass))
```

is used to print the full classification report and not only the average `roc_auc` metric as in the previous line.

This command takes as input arguments the following:

```
classification_report(y_true, y_pred)
```

`y_true` is `originalclass` for you, the ground truth and `y_pred` should be the predicted cross-validated labels/classes.

---

**You should have something like this:**

```
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X_reduced, y, cv=loo)
classification_report(originalclass, y_pred)
```

Now, the `y_pred` is already cross-validated predictions of the labels so the classification report will print the cross-validated results in terms of the classification metrics.

---

**Toy example to illustrate the above:**

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

originalclass = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
print(classification_report(originalclass, y_pred))
```

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
       1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
       2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

 micro avg       0.60      0.60      0.60         5
 macro avg       0.50      0.56      0.49         5
 weighted avg       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So just to clarify, the code that I pasted above doesn't calculate the average classification report averaged across all folds?

Comment: your initial code will not work at all. Where is `originalclass, predictedclass` constructed? They are empty

Comment: now it seems okay. `originalclass = y` can be outside the loop of course. consider upvoting and accepting my answer

Comment: So finally we are predicting our labels using the cross validated model and getting the classification report, right?

Comment: exactly. `cross_val_predict` predicts the labels using cross validations.

Comment: +1 for your help. I am also trying to run this command 
`print(np.mean(cross_val_score(model,subset,y,cv=loo,scoring='roc_auc')))`
but I am getting an error
`ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case`.

Comment: does `y` contain more than one class/label? It should because AUC is defined for a least binary problems (2 labels/classes).

Comment: `y.value_counts()` is binary only
class 0:    223
class 1:     52

Comment: `y` should be a numpy array list `[0,0,0,1,1,1]` containing the labels for each sample